# Does Macbook Air 2015 support daisy chaining monitors in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, displayport

Macbook Air models have a a mini displayport. In my eyes it should be simple to dasiy chain two monitors (as you can with thunderbolt/usb-c), yet it seems there is a limitation in the software?

Does anyone know if you can run two monitors with the lastest macOS (Catalina) on a Macbook Air?

Answer (score 1):

You can use daisy chaining with an Apple ThunderBolt display and the MacBook Air.

If you haven't got two such displays, the easiest method is to buy a Thunderbolt 2 docking station that support multiple monitors.

Comment: I have to regular USB-C monitors. Couldn't I just get a Thunderbolt 2 -> USB-C converter? Or do I need a TB2 dock specifically (not TB3)?